# Sequelize many-to-many error: user.addProjects is not a function

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to create a many-to-many relationship using sequelize, but everytime i try to use this function:

```
    user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})
```

my server crashed and I get this error:

> user.addProjects is not a function
>       at User.create.then.user

```
 var connection = new Sequelize('database', 'root', 'phase_99');

    var User = connection.define('user', {title: Sequelize.STRING});
    var Project = connection.define('project', {title: Sequelize.STRING});
    var UserProjects = connection.define('userProjects', {
        status: Sequelize.STRING
    })

    User.belongsToMany(Project, {as: 'Workers', through: UserProjects,  foreignKey: 1 })
    Project.belongsToMany(User, { as: 'Tasks', through: UserProjects, foreignKey: 1  })


    connection.sync().then(() => {
    var project = Project.create({title: 'ISD Corp'})

    User.create()
      .then(user => {

        user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})

      })
    });
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed the docs, and this function is suppose to autogenerate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code after `sync()` should be as follows

```js
connection.sync().then(() => {
    Project.create({ title: 'ISD Corp' }).then((project) => {
        User.create().then((user) => {
            user.addTask(project, { status: 'started' }).then(() => {
                // finished
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Due to the fact that you have used the `as` attribute in `belongsToMany`, your method for adding project to user is now called `addTask` or `addTasks` (in case of multiple tasks at once).

In your code the `project` variable was `Promise` instance which you tried to use in the `addProject` method - that was the first reason it would not work. Second of all, in the `addProject` in order to add additional attributes to join table, you do not need to use `through` object.

Comment: If someone is running a migration for modifications to DB how do one go about it